# Fetch $_GET or $_POST on custom My Account section in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, post, woocommerce, account

I want to load an input form in my account section of Woocommerce. But it seems that it does not `read` the form or can return a `$_GET` variable.

I added an add_filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'flxz_recurring_link', 40);
function flxz_recurring_link($menu_links)
{
    $menu_links = array_slice($menu_links, 0, 5, true)
     + array('flx-subscription' => 'Subscription')
     + array_slice($menu_links, 5, null, true);
    return $menu_links;
}
```

Then call the endpoint

```
add_action('init', 'flxz_add_endpoint');
function flxz_add_endpoint()
{
   add_rewrite_endpoint('flx-subscription', EP_PAGES);
}
```

And I want to generate a form here

```
add_action('woocommerce_account_flx-subscription_endpoint', 'flxz_my_account_endpoint_content');
function flxz_my_account_endpoint_content()
{
    $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
   var_dump( $_GET());
}
```

When I do the `var_dump`, it throws this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\shop_recurring\index.php:42 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): flexzone_my_account_endpoint_content('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php(2842): do_action('woocommerce_acc...', '') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): woocommerce_account_content('') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\myaccount\my-account.php(34): do_action('woocommerce_acc...') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-core-functions.php(208): include('C:\\xampp\\ht in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\shop_recurring\index.php on line 42
```

Thank you :)

[image]

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Woocommerce Recurring
Plugin URI: https://localhost
Description: Recurring Plug-in for Wordpress
Version: 1.0
Author: Daan 
Author URI: https://localhost
License: MIT
 */

// Load Subscription link in Woocommerce
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'flxz_recurring_link', 40);
function flxz_recurring_link($menu_links)
{
    $menu_links = array_slice($menu_links, 0, 5, true)
     + array('flx-subscription' => 'Subscription')
     + array_slice($menu_links, 5, null, true);
    return $menu_links;
}

add_action('init', 'flxz_add_endpoint');
function flxz_add_endpoint()
{
   add_rewrite_endpoint('flx-subscription', EP_PAGES);
}

add_action('woocommerce_account_flx-subscription_endpoint', 'flxz_my_account_endpoint_content');
function flxz_my_account_endpoint_content()
{
    $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
//    var_dump( $_GET());
print '
   <form action="" method="post"></form>
   <input type="text" name="Blablabla" id="Blablabla">
   </form>
   ';
}
```

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\shop_recurring\index.php:42
Can you check the callback of that hook. I think you may forgot to add it in quotes

Comment: What hook should I call? (I added the complete script, so it is more clear) :)

Comment: You want `var_dump( $_GET );`, without the `()` …

Comment: Yes of course. The problem sat in that I used $_GET() instead of $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code… $_POST works just fine. Try the following revisited code:

```
// Load Subscription link in Woocommerce
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'flxz_recurring_link', 40);
function flxz_recurring_link($menu_links)
{
    $menu_links = array_slice($menu_links, 0, 5, true)
     + array('flx-subscription' => 'Subscription')
     + array_slice($menu_links, 5, null, true);
    return $menu_links;
}

add_action('init', 'flxz_add_endpoint');
function flxz_add_endpoint()
{
   add_rewrite_endpoint('flx-subscription', EP_PAGES);
}

add_action('woocommerce_account_flx-subscription_endpoint', 'flxz_my_account_endpoint_content');
function flxz_my_account_endpoint_content()
{
    $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());

    echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="blabla" id="Blablabla" value="'.$user_info->billing_email.'"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></form>';

    echo '<br><p>' . ( isset($_POST['blabla']) ? 'Submited: ' . $_POST['blabla'] : 'Nothing is submited yet…' ) . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.